# How to populate field based on groupings?

Tags: sql, powershell

I am trying to create a PowerShell (5.1) script (Open to SQL suggestions as well using SSMS with SQL Server 2014) to eliminate manual effort of updating a very large data file exported in CSV format.

Here is what the raw data set looks like that needs updated:

```
Parent ID | Parent Owner | Sub ID | Sub Owner | Sub Hours
A                          aA       Rob Green   0
A                          aB       Rob Green   6
B                          aA       Jane Doe    4
B                          aB       Jane Doe    10
B                          aC       Bob Smith   18
C                          cA       Jane Doe    0
C                          cB       Jane Doe    6
D                          dA       Bob Smith   0
D                          dB       Bob Smith   6
E                          dE       Joe Brown   0
```

As you can see, Parent IDs can have one or many Sub Owners and Sub IDs.

My goal is to populate the Parent Owner field based on the following criteria:

***For every Parent ID set***

1. If there is only one distinct Sub Owner, then that Sub Owner should be the Parent Owner for all corresponding Parent IDs.
2. If there is only one occurrence of a Parent ID then that Sub Owner should be the Parent Owner for that Parent ID.
3. If there are multiple Sub Owners for the Parent ID, the Sub Owner with the highest summed Sub Hours should be the Parent Owner for every occurrence of that Parent ID.

To clarify, the criteria applies to the raw data above like so:

- Parent ID "A" applies to criteria 1
- Parent ID "B" applies to criteria 3
- Parent ID "C" applies to criteria 1
- Parent ID "D" applies to criteria 1
- Parent ID "E" applies to criteria 2

This is what I expect the data above to look like after completed:

```
Parent ID | Parent Owner | Sub ID | Sub Owner | Sub Hours
A           Rob Green      aA       Rob Green   0
A           Rob Green      aB       Rob Green   6
B           Bob Smith      aA       Jane Doe    4
B           Bob Smith      aB       Jane Doe    10
B           Bob Smith      aC       Bob Smith   18
C           Jane Doe       cA       Jane Doe    0
C           Jane Doe       cB       Jane Doe    6
D           Bob Smith      dA       Bob Smith   0
D           Bob Smith      dB       Bob Smith   6
E           Joe Brown      dE       Joe Brown   0
```

My biggest struggle is criteria 3. I cannot wrap my head around how to do this. Can anyone give me an idea of how I can get my expected output using PS or SQL?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *particular* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: I don't think that I insinuated that SO is a free code-writing service nor did I ask for a full blown solution. 
"Can anyone give me an idea of how I can get my expected output using PS or SQL?" 


I'm asking to be pointed in the right direction for what I need to achieve. My PS code won't help anyone here because it only contains import-csv and an export-csv. I'm at a complete loss and how to achieve a solution for my problem above, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I vowed myself that SQL is strictly taboo for me*. However, below's an example of pure PowerShell solution (and I'm pretty sure that it's convertible to SQL simply):

```
# mimic SQL output
$SqlOutput = @"
Parent ID|Parent Owner|Sub ID|Sub Owner|Sub Hours
A||aA|Rob Green|0
A||aB|Rob Green|6
B||aA|Jane Doe|4
B||aB|Jane Doe|10
B||aC|Bob Smith|18
C||cA|Jane Doe|0
C||cB|Jane Doe|6
D||dA|Bob Smith|0
D||dB|Bob Smith|6
E||dE|Joe Brown|0
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'

# compute an auxiliary variable
$SqlOutputGroups = $SqlOutput | 
    Group-Object -Property 'Parent ID', 'Sub Owner' | 
      ForEach-Object { 
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
          'Parent ID' = ( $_.Name -split ', ')[0]
          'Sub Owner' = ( $_.Name -split ', ')[1]
          Hours = ( $_.Group | 
            Measure-Object -Property 'Sub Hours' -Sum).Sum
        }
      } 

# compute Criterium3  as a hashtable
$SqlOutputCriterium3 = @{}
$SqlOutputGroups | Group-Object -Property 'Parent ID' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $SqlOutputCriterium3[$_.Name] = ($_.Group | 
            Sort-Object -Property Hours |
                Select-Object -Last 1).'Sub Owner'
    }

# apply Criterium3
$SqlOutput | ForEach-Object {
    $_.'Parent Owner' = $SqlOutputCriterium3.$($_.'Parent ID')
}

# show result in a table format
$SqlOutput | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\45963820.ps1`

> ```
> Parent ID Parent Owner Sub ID Sub Owner Sub Hours
> --------- ------------ ------ --------- ---------
> A         Rob Green    aA     Rob Green 0        
> A         Rob Green    aB     Rob Green 6        
> B         Bob Smith    aA     Jane Doe  4        
> B         Bob Smith    aB     Jane Doe  10       
> B         Bob Smith    aC     Bob Smith 18       
> C         Jane Doe     cA     Jane Doe  0        
> C         Jane Doe     cB     Jane Doe  6        
> D         Bob Smith    dA     Bob Smith 0        
> D         Bob Smith    dB     Bob Smith 6        
> E         Joe Brown    dE     Joe Brown 0
> ```

Note that *Criterium 3* **covers** criteria *1* and *2* but **does not suffice** if more *Sub Owners* have the same highest sum of *Sub Hours*  for a particular *Parent ID* (e.g in case of `B||aA|Jane Doe|8` instead of `B||aA|Jane Doe|4` in the above example, then *Jane Doe* has sum of *Sub Hours* =18 as well as *Bob Smith* in *Parent ID*=B).